# Gtk scroll window size in a grid

Tags: python, gtk

Experimenting with Gtk+3 in python.

Trying to add a "Gtk.TreeView" inside a scroll window container to a grid window along with an entry box. The problem is that the scroll area is tiny and as a result you can barely see any of the scroll window/TreeView. Here is an image of the output:

[image]

The relevant code is:

```
scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()    # Create scroll window
scroll.add(self.MatchTree)       # Adds the TreeView to the scroll container

grid = Gtk.Grid()                # Create grid container
self.add(Grid)                   # Add grid to window (self)
Grid.add(scroll)                 # Add scroll window to grid
Grid.attach_next_to(self.Entry, scroll, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)  # Attach entry to bottom of grid.
```

So how do you control the size of the scroll area?

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is to set the `hexpand` and `vexpand` attributes of the `GtkScrolledWindow` to `True`. You can do this on object creation like this:

```
scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(hexpand=True, vexpand=True)
```

If you are up to it, I recommend you use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) to work your program's interface, it makes a lot simpler to work out this kind of problems, since you have easy access to all the widgets properties.

Comment: Great, thank you for that and the advice. I've tried Glade but thought it was just another level of abstraction on a topic I was still trying to grasp. But you're right in terms of showing a user all the options. I will keep this in mind!

Comment: I understand, sometimes is better to start off doing things by hand to get to know how to use it better. Still, when you find that something you wrote doesn't work as you intended, you can use Glade to test out different properties conbinations to make it work (as matter of fact, that's how I found out the problem on your code d:)

Comment: similar for python2 (pygtk) ?