# How to expand the GTK window containing a really tiny GRID inside a scrolled window?

Tags: gtk

I have a code containing GTK entries in a GRID, my goal is to append them into the GRID to make a table of values, something like a "spreadsheet". The entries are in the GRID, and the GRID is in a GTK Scrolled window, which is in the main window.

Yet, I am not getting the expected result. The GRID is really tiny, it can be expanded.

Here is what I am getting (image):

[image: What I am getting]

Here is what I want (image):
[image: What I want]

Here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *mainwindow;
    mainwindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow), "Example");
    g_signal_connect(mainwindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    
    int n = 5;
    
    GtkWidget *entries[n][n];   
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *scrolledwindow; 
    
    grid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 5);
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 3);
    
    scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            entries[i][j] = gtk_entry_new();

            gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), entries[i][j], i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), grid);
    
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainwindow), scrolledwindow);

    gtk_widget_show_all(mainwindow);

    gtk_main();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Searching in the internet, I have found this problem:
[Gtk scroll window size in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250927/gtk-scroll-window-size-in-a-grid), but it's in Python, and I don't know, but NULL and NULL, what values I must atribute to a and b in this command: `gtk_scrolled_window_new(a, b);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`gtk_scrolled_window_set_propagate_natural_width`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.ScrolledWindow.get_propagate_natural_width.html) and [`gtk_scrolled_window_set_propagate_natural_height`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.ScrolledWindow.set_propagate_natural_height.html) functions from `GtkScrolledWindow`.

For example, in your snippet:

```c
    // ...

    scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    
    // Use the child widget's natural dimensions when requesting the scrollwindow's
    // own natural size:
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_propagate_natural_width(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolledwindow), true);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_propagate_natural_height(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolledwindow), true);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!